# #include file derived from macro __FILE__?

Tags: c++, macros, include, c-preprocessor

Observe the following program:

```
#include __FILE__
main(){}
```

The preprocessor gets stuck in infinite recursion including a copy of itself inside itself and complaining about `main()` already being defined.

---

If I can use macros to include files, 
can I derive a file name based on `__FILE__` and include it?

---

For example, I'd like to include `"foo.h"` whilst inside `"foo.cpp"`, but derive it from `__FILE__`.

- [`##`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) will concatenate macros.
- It is also possible to [Stringify](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification) macros.

Can it be done with the preprocessor?

Comment: You can't edit the file name, and concatenation of adjacent string literals occurs in phase 6 of the translation, but preprocessing occurs in phase 4, so you can't use string concatenation.  That means it is not possible to build a file name that can be included by the preprocessor from `__FILE__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard specifies three forms of `#include`:

```
#include <file>
#include "file"
#include ANYTHING ELSE
```

In the former two cases, no macro expansion takes place, so there's no way to vary the behavior.  In the third case, C99 says (§6.10.2p4):

> The preprocessing tokens after `#include` in the directive are [macro-expanded]. The directive resulting after all replacements shall match one of the two previous forms [footnote: Note that adjacent string literals are not concatenated into a single string literal].  The method by which a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a < and a > preprocessing token pair or a pair of " characters is combined into a single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined.

Slightly different, but effectively equivalent, wording appears in C++98 §16.2p4.

Any sentence with "shall" in it imposes a hard requirement: in this case, the program is ill-formed if `ANYTHING ELSE` expands to anything but a sequence of tokens beginning with `<` and ending with `>`, or beginning and ending with `"`.  The exact interpretation of that sequence of tokens is implementation defined, but note that the footnote specifically forbids string-literal concatenation.

So, as the expansion of `__FILE__` is a string constant, the only ways to use it in an `#include` are

```
#include __FILE__
```

which, as you discovered, leads to infinite recursion, and

```
#define LT <
#define GT >
#include LT __FILE__ etc GT
```

which has amusing, but useless, effects on all the compilers I can conveniently test.  Assuming that the above is in a file named `test.c`:

- GCC attempts to open a file named `"test.c" etc`, with the quotation marks and space included verbatim.
- clang is even more literal, and looks for that same filename but with leading and trailing spaces.
- MSVC macro-expands *only* the `LT` (it is my considered opinion that this is a conformance violation), complains that there is no matching `>`, and then attempts to open a file named `__FILE__ etc GT`.

([GCC's behavior is documented here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/cpp/Computed-Includes.html); you are on your own for anything else.)

tl;dr: There is no way to do what you want from inside the preprocessor.  I recommend working out the name of the file-to-be-included from your build system and notifying the compiler of it with a `-D` switch (on a Unixy system you will need double quotation, `-DINCLUDEME='"includeme.h"'`; I don't speak CMD)

Answer (score 0):

The best I've come up with is this:

```
#define foo(x) #x
#include foo(x)
```

> prog.cpp:2:16: error: x: No such file or directory